# Есть массив строк и необходимо профильтровать массив через filter найдя те в которых нет цифр

Tags: javascript, массивы, qregularexpression

Есть массив str:

```
 let str = [
        "ifdaohohadvjnvajcnjn",
        "7149038hewuusvh",
        "kahfdihavsn",
        "98132rur9",
        "dfdfrfcsd",
        "39217312089",
        "adsufnjinadsnvjcs1",
      ];
```

Необходимо через filter найти те в которых нет цифр

Comment: Понятно... И как? Смогли?

Comment: Нет,что делать?я только понял что через test надо роботать

Comment: Нет? Тогда идите читайте книжку, статью или видео урок по регулярным выражениям. Настоятельно рекомендую вам ознакомится со страницей [на MDN посвящённой регулярным выражениям](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: не знаю конечно можно ли так: let z = str.filter((x) => /\d/.test(x) == false);Результат-то конечно выбивает что надо но тут вроде как через регулярку надо

Comment: А там у вас всё правильно и как надо :) Через регулярку нельзя фильтровать массив, это нужно делать методом `filter`. Именно так вы и сделали, добавьте ваш код в вопрос или сами ответьте на свой вопрос. Вопрос можно отредактировать кнопкой [**править**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1471420/edit).

Comment: нет,у меня именно задания регулировать массив через регулярку

Comment: Вы по моему как-то не так поняли задание, потому что через регулярные выражения нельзя фильтровать массив, это бессмысленно. Вы сделали как надо, если вам скажут фильтровать массив через регулярные выражения, значит скорее всего имеют в виду используя метод `filter`, а если нет, то тогда это абсолютно неправильно, ведь они (регулярные выражения) работают только со строками.

Answer (score 1):

```
let z = str.filter((x) => /\d/.test(x) == false);
```